this.driver.createCDPSession Selenium NodeJS cant call cdp session
i've been trying to block some request in selenium nodejs
i create CDPSession, but it's not callable
 async launchBrowser(UA) {
        try {
            await this.startProxyServer();
    
            const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
            const options = new chrome.Options();
    
            options.addArguments('--blink-settings=animationPolicy=none');

            options.addArguments('--proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8080'); // Use local proxy server
    
            if (this.browserSettings.convertToEnglish) options.addArguments('--lang=en-US');
    
            this.log('Using mobile browser settings with user agent:' + UA);
            options.addArguments('--user-agent=' + UA);
            options.addArguments('--window-size=375,812');
    
            if (this.browserSettings.incognitoMode) options.addArguments('--incognito');
            options.addArguments('--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-gpu');
    
            console.log('Initializing browser...');
            this.driver = await new Builder()
                .forBrowser('chrome')
                .setChromeOptions(options)
                .build();
            this.isDriverActive = true;
            this.log('Browser launched with the specified settings.');
    
            const cdpConnection = await this.driver.createCDPSession();
            await cdpConnection.send('Network.enable');
    
            await cdpConnection.send('Network.setBlockedURLs', {
                urls: [
                    '*://images.tokopedia.net/*',
                    '*://assets.tokopedia.net/*',
                    '*://*.adservice.google.com/*',
                    '*://*.analytics.google.com/*'
                ]
            });
            this.log('Blocked specific network requests using CDP.');
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error launching browser:', error);
            this.log(`Error launching browser: ${error.message}`);
            throw error;
        }
    }

how to fix this issue?
i want actually block some request withing selenium js , but i don't know what was wrong
doing research online it just show for python or C# only
